# Configuring User Registration with aws PHP SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm Developing web Application that user can register by them self and log in after confirmation.i used AWS JavaScript for that it's working great.but since the access key is visible for everybody i planed to do it in Using PHP-AWS SDK.but why all the example aws providing foe EC2 or S3, i couldn't find any for cognito in php.can someone guide me or provide a basic example for this scenario..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently Cognito supports high level SDKs for only for Android, iOS, and Javascript, but doesn't support high level SDK for PHP. You can use the low level PHP-AWS SDK which will give you access to calling the API methods. The methods found at the following link are accessible in the AWS SDK and can be called:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.CognitoIdentityProvider.CognitoIdentityProviderClient.html

Comment: Thank you for your Response.can you explain littlebit more what you mean by high level SDKs please.I'm mainly concern about creating sessions.that's why i try to move to php. is it unsecure to use cognito in javascript ..?(since anyone can see the access key)

Comment: By high level SDKs I mean SDKs where implementations of the Secure Remote Password protocol are available. Those would be the SDKs I mentioned above. For PHP, you can call the low level service APIs that I mentioned above. The access token should be available only in the current browser tab.